# access violation writing to 2d array in c

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to initialise a 2d array, and for some reason I'm getting an exception whenever I try to enter a value into the array.

I'm passing it to the function in a struct, if that makes a difference?

Here's the code:

```
#define board_size 10

typedef struct {
    int b[board_size][board_size];
} board;

board dead_state();     // initialise a dead board state

void main() {
    board test_board = dead_state();

    for (int i = 0; i < board_size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board_size - 1; i++) {
            test_board.b[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

board dead_state() {
    // generate the matrix, set all values to 0, return
    board deadboard;

    for (int i = 0; i < board_size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board_size - 1; i++) {
            deadboard.b[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    return deadboard;
}
```

edit: problem solved, thanks to hyde's comment: i am blind and cannot see, apparently.

Comment: Your board coordinates go from 0 to 9. Your loops go from 0 to 8. Is this intentional?

Comment: And your inner loops have `i++` when they should have `j++`.

Comment: wow, those are some basic mistakes. i haven't touched an ide over the holidays, i must have gotten very rusty. thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @hyde yep, that was the issue - i cannot read. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have what looks like a typo.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < board_size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board_size - 1; i++) {
            test_board.b[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Both loops increment `i`, which means `i` goes out of bounds. You likely meant for the inner loop to increment `j`, but I don't know why you're only incrementing `i` and `j` up to `8`, instead of `9`.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it, there was a comment of a similar nature. thank you!